# SQL Server LCK_M_S only happens in production

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, blocking

I have a stored procedure that is called by a SQL Server 2012 report that is taking an age to run in production compared to development because of a blocking session `lck_m_s`

The stored procedure runs instantaneously when executed in SQL Server Management Studio and also works well when called as part of the report from a dev laptop via Visual Studio.

When the report is uploaded to the production server this blocking issue appears.

How can I find out what is causing the `lck_m_s` issue when in production?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Execute this query when the problem happens again:

```
select * from 
sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks t
inner join sys.dm_exec_connections c on c.session_id = t.blocking_session_id
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(c.most_recent_sql_handle) as h1
```

It will give you the spid of the session that caused blocking, on which resource was blocked, and text of the most rcent query for that session. This should give you a solid starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options

1. Set up the blocked process report. Essentially, you set the `blocked process threshold (s)` system configuration to a non-zero number of seconds and set up an event notification on the `BLOCKED_PROCESS_REPORT` event. You'll get an XML report each time any process is blocked for more than the threshold you've set. The downside to this is that it'll be for anything getting blocked, not just your procedure, but you'll get whomever is holding the non-compatible lock in the report.
2. Set up an extended events session for your procedure to capture the `lock_released` event where the duration is longer than you care to wait. The upside is that this is extremely targeted and you can define the session so that you get very little noise. The downside is that you won't know what process is holding the incompatible lock (though you will get a pretty detailed description of what the locked resource is to further your investigation).